# What exactly is the "resolution" parameter of numpy float

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I am seeking some more understanding about the "resolution" parameter of a numpy float (I guess any computer defined float for that matter).

Consider the following script:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.finfo(10.1)
print a
```

I get an output which among other things prints out:

```
precision=15   resolution= 1.0000000000000001e-15
max= 1.797(...)e+308
min= -max
```

The numpy documentation specifies: "resolution: (floating point number of the appropriate type) The approximate decimal resolution of this type, i.e., 10**-precision." [source](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html)

resolution is derived from precision, but unfortunately this definition is somewhat circular "precision (int): The approximate number of decimal digits to which this kind of float is precise." [source](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html)

I understand that floating point numbers are merely finite representations of real numbers and therefore have error in their representation, and that precision is probably a measure of this deviation. But practically, does it mean that I should expect results to be erroneous if I preform operations using numbers less than the resolution? How can I quantify the error, for say addition, of two floating point numbers given their precision? If the resolution is as "large" as 1e-15, why would the smallest allowable number be on the order of 1e-308?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The short answer is "*dont' confuse [`numpy.finfo`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html) with [`numpy.spacing`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/numpy.spacing?fulldoc=1)*".

`finfo` operates on the `dtype`, while `spacing` operates on the value.

### Background Information

First, though, some general explanation:

---

The key part to understand is that floating point numbers are similar to scientific notation.  Just like you'd write 0.000001 as `1.0 x 10^-6`, floats are similar to `c x 2^q`.  In other words, they have two separate parts - a coefficient (`c`, a.k.a. "significand") and an exponent (`q`).  These two values are stored as integers.

Therefore, how closely a value can be represented (let's think of this as the degree of discretization) is a function of both parts, and *depends on the magnitude of the value*.

However, the "precision" (as referred to by `np.finfo`) is essentially the number of significant digits if the number were written in base-10 scientific notation.  The "resolution" is the resolution of the coefficient (part in front) if the value were written in the same base-10 scientific notation (i.e. `10^-precision`). In other words, both are only a function of the coefficient.

### Numpy-specific

For `numpy.finfo`, "precision" and "resolution" are simply the inverse of each other.  *Neither one tells you how closely a particular number is being represented*. They're purely a function of the `dtype`.

Instead, if you're worried about the absolute degree of discretization, use `numpy.spacing(your_float)`. This will return the difference in the next largest value in that particular format (e.g. it's different for a `float32` than a `float64`).

### Examples

As an example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.spacing(10.1)
Out[2]: 1.7763568394002505e-15

In [3]: np.spacing(10000000000.1)
Out[3]: 1.9073486328125e-06

In [4]: np.spacing(1000000000000.1)
Out[4]: 0.0001220703125

In [5]: np.spacing(100000000000000.1)
Out[5]: 0.015625

In [6]: np.spacing(10000000000000000.1)
Out[6]: 2.0
```

But the precision and resolution don't change:

```
In [7]: np.finfo(10.1).precision
Out[7]: 15

In [8]: np.finfo(10000000000000000.1).precision
Out[8]: 15

In [9]: np.finfo(10.1).resolution
Out[9]: 1.0000000000000001e-15

In [10]: np.finfo(10000000000000000000.1).resolution
Out[10]: 1.0000000000000001e-15
```

Also note that all of these depend on the data type that you're using:

```
In [11]: np.spacing(np.float32(10.1))
Out[11]: 9.5367432e-07

In [12]: np.spacing(np.float32(10000000000000.1))
Out[12]: 1048576.0

In [13]: np.finfo(np.float32).precision
Out[13]: 6

In [14]: np.finfo(np.float32).resolution
Out[14]: 1e-06

In [15]: np.spacing(np.float128(10.1))
Out[15]: 8.6736173798840354721e-19

In [16]: np.spacing(np.float128(10000000000000.1))
Out[16]: 9.5367431640625e-07

In [17]: np.finfo(np.float128).precision
Out[17]: 18

In [18]: np.finfo(np.float128).resolution
Out[18]: 1.0000000000000000007e-18
```

---

### Specific Questions

Now on to your specific questions:

> But practically, does it mean that I should expect results to be erroneous if I preform operations using numbers less than the resolution?

No, because the precision/resolution (in `numpy.finfo` terms) is only a function of the coefficient, and doesn't take into account the exponent.  Very small and very large numbers have the same "precision", but that's not an absolute "error".

As a rule of thumb, when using the "resolution" or "precision" terms from `finfo`, think of scientific notation. If we're operating on small numbers with similar magnitudes, we don't need to worry about much.

Let's take the decimal math case with 6 significant digits (somewhat similar to a `float32`):

```
1.20000 x 10^-19 + 2.50000 x 10^-20 => 1.45000 x 10^19
```

However, if we operate on numbers with wildly different magnitudes but limited precision (again, 6 significant digits):

```
1.20000 x 10^6 + 2.50000 x 10^-5 => 1.20000
```

We'll start to see the effects quite clearly.

> How can I quantify the error, for say addition, of two floating point numbers given their precision?

Use `np.spacing(result)`.

> If the resolution is as "large" as 1e-15, why would the smallest allowable number be on the order of 1e-308?

Again, the "resolution" in this case doesn't take into account the exponent, just the part in front.

---

Hopefully that helps clarify things somewhat.  All of this is a bit confusing, and everyone gets bitten by it at some point.  It's good to try to build up a bit of intuition about it and to know what functions to call to find out exactly in your platform-of-choice!

Comment: Wow, terrific and detailed answer! Thanks very much!