# How can float32 variable contain a value less that 10^-18?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is the problem:

```
tf.constant(1e-7, tf.float32)*0.00000000001
Out[25]: <tf.Tensor: id=2645779, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1e-18>
```

The result should be zero, right? not 1e-18 ! cause that is beyond the single floating point resolution. I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465481/what-exactly-is-the-resolution-parameter-of-numpy-float also this: https://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premise is incorrect.  The exponent is 8 bits signed integer, or [-128, 127].  This gives a base-10 magnitude range of roughly [-39, +39].

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Then why is it that in my neural nets with float32 accuracy, I can never find a weight that has a value less than 10^-7 ?

Comment: I don't know for sure; it depends on the framework's training engine.  I suspect that your TF engine drives tiny values to 0 for processing efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Floating points don't store like integers do, there's a special format they use defined by the IEEE that dedicates a section of them to the exponent, this gives them a range of E-128 to E127 in binary.

[This site might be helpful for your understanding](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)