# Precision when adding up numbers

Tags: python, scipy, floating-accuracy, runge-kutta

When solving a coupled system of differential equations the resulting solutions, say x, y and z, must satisfy the following relation: x+y=z. However, due to what I think is the numerical accuracy of Python the relation ceases to be true as x+y gets stuck and becomes constant when it shouldn't (I attach the plot so you can see what I mean).

Is there a quick way to improve the accuracy (if that is the problem) or to sort out this numeric issue? I revised the equations, and everything is OK. The integrator I am using is already provided by SciPy and is well-suited for this kind of problems (RK45).

[image]

Comment: [decimal.Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) attempts to resolve the floating point inaccuracies of binary data - it might help.

Comment: If using numpy arrays consider using `.isclose` instead of `==`

Comment: You can try using the `numpy.longdouble` datatype. That will have more precision than float64. If you are using float32, then try with float64.

Comment: If using scipy.integrate.RK45 are you using the `rtol, atol` parameters?

Comment: @wwii yes, I'm using both

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466516/2823755

Comment: `np.spacing(1e-22)` --> `1.1754943508222875e-38`